# How to parse Json from Blob in Azure SQL Database

Tags: json, sql-server, azure, blob, openrowset

I am not sure what is the most efficient way to do this, should I be using openrowset to read file to a single varchar(max) column (in the table) and cross appy OPENJSON (something like below), or is there a more efficient way?

```sql
SELECT * FROM  
OPENROWSET.....
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON ( j.Blobdata )  
WITH (   
              source_object   varchar(200) '$.source_object.Number' ,  
              Date     datetime     '$.Order.Date',  
              Customer varchar(200) '$.AccountNumber',  
              Quantity int          '$.Item.Quantity'  
 )
```

Comment: Sounds efficient enough, unless you want to do it in some kind of client language (C# or Powershell etc). I assume you are using `OPENROWSET...SINGLE_NCLOB`

Comment: Hi @Gokhan,We can't say which is the most efficient way to do this, both are efficient enough. They are all recommended by official document. Just choose the way you like best. If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

We can load files directly into Azure SQL Database from Azure Blob Storage with T-SQL BULK INSERT command or the OPENROWSET function.

We can't say which is the most efficient way to do this, both are efficient enough. They are all recommended by official document. Just choose the way you like best.

For more details, please ref this doucment: [Import JSON documents from Azure Blob Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/import-json-documents-into-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#import-json-documents-from-azure-blob-storage)

HTH.

Comment: If there are lets say 1000 json files to be imported, the only way to accomplish this is to call OPENROWSET or BULK INSERT a 1000 times? (Files are not necessarily all in the same folder or all files in the folder are included therefore wildcard (*) will not work)

Comment: @Gokhan you question didn't say you have so many json files. That'a an different question. If both the json files have same schema, we need use other ways.

Comment: Let's say there our 1000 json files each containing a single record or in some cases up to 100 records, calling openrowset 1000 times does not seem to be efficient (checking file access to blob etc per file and adding delay)

Comment: Hi @Gokhan, I can understand you. But you current question is which is the most efficient way to load JSON file into Azure SQL database, not multiple files in to Azure SQL database. And the files may have different records, actually they are different questions you know.  I would suggest you modify your question or post a new question. Thank you! Per my experience, if we have so may files and want load them to Azure SQL, we need other ETL tools, like Data Factory.

Comment: @Gokhan do you have any other concerns?